# webView loadDocument for special character(#,%) in iOS

Tags: html, ios, webview

I want to load a local html page with the following url:
"webView.loadDocument("./Html/error.html#401");"

But It converts my link to:
/Html/error.html%23401
and does not redirect.

Can someone help me to not to convert "#" into "%23"

Comment: Which language are you writing in? `UIWebView` is an Objective-C class, and `webView.loadDocument("./Html/error.html#401");` is not valid Objective-C syntax. Where are you calling this from? Please post some more code.

Comment: that was a wrapper for objC.